# Typing a generic wrapper function to act as a logger?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a generic JS function that wraps any function, in such a way that when the wrapper is called it will execute the wrapped function, log the event (input, and output of the function) and then return the output, resulting in "transparent" logging. My problem is that trying to move this function to TS and conserving the type information for the wrapped function and output is proving to be a little complex.

Here's where I'm at currently:

```
const syncLogger = <T>(f: T) => (...args: unknown[]): ReturnType<T> => {
  let value;
  try {
    value = f(...args);
    functionLogger('info', f, value, ...args); // actual logging
  } catch (error) {
    functionLogger('error', f, error.message, ...args); //actual logging
    throw error;
  }
  return value;
};
```

and this is how it's supposed to be used:

```
const myLoggedFunction = syncLogger(originalFunction);
```

The main problem lies in `args`, the list of n arguments that I used to use as the functions' input: I see no way of letting TS know that those arguments correspond exactly with the arguments of the original function to be wrapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make `syncLogger` generic both in the tuple of arguments `A` and the return type `R` of the function, like this:

```
const syncLogger = <A extends any[], R>(f: (...a: A) => R) => (
  ...args: A
): R => {
  let value;
  try {
    value = f(...args);
    functionLogger("info", f, value, ...args); // actual logging
  } catch (error) {
    functionLogger("error", f, error.message, ...args); //actual logging
    throw error;
  }
  return value;
};
```

This should work as you expect:

```
function originalFunction(x: string, y: number): boolean {
  return (x <= y.toFixed())
}

const myLoggedFunction = syncLogger(originalFunction); // okay
// const myLoggedFunction: (x: string, y: number) => boolean

const bool = myLoggedFunction("121", 123); // info, originalFunction, true, "121", 123
console.log(bool) // true
```

In fact, in many cases this will work even when the original function is itself generic, due to support added in TypeScript 3.4 for [inferring higher-order function types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions):

```
const loggingItself = syncLogger(syncLogger);
// TS3.3-: 
// const loggingItself: (...args: any[]) => (...args: any[]) => {} 
// TS3.4+: 
// const loggingItself: <A extends any[], R>(f: (...a: A) => R) => (...args: A) => R
```

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEBk4HMsFMBOAFAHSkCG+WAzgFyJlgCeAlHQG5wwAmiA3gFCJEEBFTgAbXMXHYS5SlWYBufgF9+-EWCpREVRpEw4CiALyIAPAEFEuAB5RcYLlXpMA2gF0ANIgBKAHyEwHRyxGR0VsxmAf7RprGEgoik4QqR-Kz+MXzJkrpsZOIguCpCUPiMuUJChcW4ZshhFNTKyUIo0PBgRnhEAEQwYMBw-b7AvnUlvqktikqIAPSL9NAgRYgyOENYyarCZFAQABaIhAT4cPjRAjXI4F0Y2H2E-RdXY8i+7-jEALa4KhUMh4GbyVoLZZkNYbLZYHbtRBQY6XADutnwl3wZUQ6iE+FwUBA+CQU1KahU-E6aCQVxg8LARQAYg8aYQ7HQdPgdr5GHQwCA-gAjAhZIVwCS4BjVRAEokks52SzmRjEKBwJkwOy4LiEZjMNQaLQ6RB-Ri9HUs1DdRr6QzPAiEOkM5ms7rKJYrOAAazIjH4y2Eol0ZotXCtjzAoQ5egqPMQfMQAuFopy4slDCNwcQ6fEjVDDvDboQrwAjAAmUufCsAZg9gaGI18zqGrutCF8FWmiH6FarvlrWe0kukslz0UDXdwQ5NcJ2AEkoFRcOJgLaDBALUQ7ZuHdcVIGACoAZRrxBrAFo6IBeDcARHsBlbG3RzsBYRfL1ehWbpNyMLzxRJv2oOgGD-TwAL4fYH0QE8zwAFgAahvQAoPegp9NmeBclxXEJLBsexHGcVxQK8XxAmCL9yEiCC-Ag5ofyiHI-CAA)

Comment: Yup, that works perfectly! For some reason it hadn't occurred to me that it is possible to use more than one type variable. Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually you should be able to do it with a single type variable for the function type, the way you were doing it, but there are some [limitations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31418) there I'd like to avoid.